# How do i use IntelliTrace to capture Debug information for Windows Service

Tags: visual-studio-2012, intellitrace

I am using VS2012 and would like to capture Debug information, so that i can step through the Code in VS2012.

I have seen example, for .exe and Web,  but how can collect debug information for Windows Service.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not an officially supported scenario it is possible, though as a warning the steps are a bit involved. Check out this blog post for a write up of what needs to be done. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msaffer/archive/2011/02/23/using-intellitrace-with-services.aspx